# How to make Git repo in a parent folder realize the a Git repo in a subfolder was removed?

Tags: git

Let me explain the mistakes I made that led to this. For school I have downloaded some example projects for a particular coding topic that they wanted us to have. I stored them all in parent a folder where I established a git repo. The intention was to push this parent folder remotely rather than a bunch of these projects. So, I tried to go through all the example projects to remove their .git files (I imagine they were git files that the school had for their own purposes). But I missed one.

Next, I did the command "git add ." in my parent folder and committed, but I missed the warning that I've added another git repository inside a  current one. I then pushed my parent folder to a remote repository, and I see that this project which I forgot to remove the .git file from is not accessible on the remote. I have since deleted the .git file for this project, but whenever I try recommitting the parent and pushing, nothing happens (it seems like the parent git doesn't detect a change) and it's still not accessible on the remote.

Do you know how I can fix this outside of straight up deleting the repos and doing it over from scratch?

Comment: Note: the two keywords here for learning more about what you did are *submodule* and *gitlink*. What you did made what I like to call a "half-assed submodule" (a bare gitlink); Git doesn't really have a term for this (other than "gitlink", but that doesn't cover the "oops" aspect here).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$ git rm --cached inner_repo
$ git add inner_repo
```

`git status` should then show `inner_repo` as `deleted` and all its contents as `new file`. Then commit as usual.